# Extract points automatically from GeoPDF

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, geopdf

I have a GeoPDF file which have some small icons (e.g. triangle, small man, small boat, circle, and so on..). I need to extract these `icons` in a point shapefile - automatically. Is there any plugin or script to do this? I need to mention that I use QGIS.

Comment: did you check https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/geopdf-to-shp? never tried, but was one of the first results with google.

Comment: Unfourtunately it didn`t work...

Comment: is the geopdf available online?

Comment: When you use *MyGeodata Converter* try to convert GeoPDF into KML/KMZ firstly and afterwards into shp. In QGIS I recommend using [`gdal`](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html#pdf-geospatial-pdf).

Answer (score 3):

If it's actually a GeoPDF, then you will be able to open it using the "Add Vector Layer" tool in QGIS and opening the PDF directly. If that fails, then it's not a real GeoPDF file and is probably a "georeferenced" PDF only (in which case you'll only be able to open it as a raster file)